# Installing PongoOS fork on Debian results in no makefile binaries

Tags: debian, software-installation, make, github, xfce4-terminal

I am attempting to install [this fork of PongoOS](https://github.com/konradybcio/pongoOS) onto Debian 12.1 using [these instructions](https://github.com/SoMainline/linux-apple-resources/blob/master/HOWTO.md) and the last step I have taken was enter the following into the terminal:

```
EMBEDDED_CC=clang EMBEDDED_LDFLAGS=-fuse-ld=/usr/bin/ld64 STRIP=cctools-strip make all
```

The next step is to execute Pongo.bin using the following terminal command:

```
/path/to/checkra1n -v -V -p -c -k ./build/Pongo.bin
```

The problem is the fact that pongoOS/checkra1n/build does not have Pongo.bin, nor any of the other Makefile binaries listed on the GitHub page. Entering the first command against results in this message from the terminal:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
```

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122404/makefile-make-no-rule-to-make-target-all-stop) says that this message means that there is no makefile. How to I get this makefile to receive those binaries. I apologize if this is a foolish question, as I am new to the world of GNU/Linux.

Comment: I usually don't install anything  outside the debian distros, or you wind up with frankendebian.

Comment: PongoOS seems to be more like a jailbreak/installation toolkit for installing Linux on Apple iOS/iPadOS devices, than something you install on a x86 Debian system. After building PongoOS, the next step would be to build a Linux ARM kernel suitable for the target device. That, together with an initramfs file and a device tree file, would then be fed to the target device using the PongoOS tool.

Comment: @telcoM My goal is to is to jailbreak an old iPhone 5s to install a fork of PongoOS onto it in an attempt to breathe life into an otherwise $300 paperweight. I've managed to install checkra1n onto it but not much else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "the next step" command line is step #6 in the instructions you linked.

Step #2 (`git clone https://github.com/konradybcio/pongoOS`) should have produced a `pongoOS` directory, and step #3 (`cd pongoOS`) whould have set it as your current working directory. To execute step #6, **you should still be in that directory**.

A "makefile" is not a binary, but a specially-formatted text file. The `pongoOS` directory produced by step #2 should contain a number of directories and five or so files: one of these is named simply `Makefile`, and that's what the `make` command is looking for.

Normally, the `make` command expects to find a file named either `Makefile` or `makefile` *in the current working directory*. There are ways to tell it to look into some other directory, but that is not the normal way to use it.

---

The [`Makefile` in the pongoOS distribution](https://github.com/konradybcio/pongoOS/blob/master/Makefile#L111C1-L114C1) also includes a `git submodule update --init --recursive` operation, which should produce the `pongoOS/newlib/Makefile`, which is required by a subsequent child `make all` invocation in that directory.

If the `git submodule update` failed - e.g. because the Git repository it relies on could not be downloaded -  it is possible that there is still no Makefile in the `newlib` sub-directory, and that might have caused the error message. But then, the messages should have been like:

```
make: Entering directory '<some directory>/pongoOS/newlib'
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop.
make: Leaving directory '<some directory>/pongoOS/newlib'
```

and there should have been an error message from the `git submodule update` operation before that.

But if you really saw **only** the `make: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop.` message, then I'm afraid you must have been mistaken at some point: the pongoOS repository [clearly contains a Makefile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/konradybcio/pongoOS/master/Makefile) and it has the `all` target defined. So either you entered the `make` command in a wrong directory, or there was something else wrong in the previous steps, so not all the necessary files were actually downloaded into their proper locations.

Makefiles describe the build process, which can be arbitrarily complex. Usually a `make` process will produce a lot of output, most of it just informative. But when trying to fix an error, those informative messages might be necessary to figure out which part of the build process actually caused the error.

Comment: I was in the `pongoOS` directory when I executed step #6, but there was still no `pongoOS/build/Pongo.bin` in there. I had to `sudo apt-get install llvm` to get the make command working. I will wipe everything from my system and try again later this evening, as there is a new error message.